# json to save and load file

Tags: python, json

forgive me if there's a formatting problem as I'm new to this! I'm supposed to save my game and load it using import json but I'm clueless as how to do it. basically it's to prompt the user to input a number at a location and if the user wants to save, it should save the turn number and the current table with all the numbers inside. Also how do I load the information after I save it?

```
table = [ ['4','4','4','0'],\
            ['   ','9','9','0'],\
            ['5', '0','   ','2'],\
            ['   ','   ','4','4']]
while turn < 16:
        print('\nTurn',turn+1,'\n')
... code for user input
... code to place numbers inside table    
        print(table)
```

Comment: take a look at the json module (dumps and loads specifically) https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)